# SQL Grouping data and setting relevance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, group-by

This result set is obtained from an already complex piece of sql but im stuck trying to filter the data down.

-Items with active = 1  and approved = 0 mean they are live

-Items with active = 0 and approved = 0 mean they are pending however, the one with the most recent updateddate is the latest version.

Because not all the fields against the same versionId are unique, i'm unable to select MAX(updateDate), [all the other fields] group by [all other fields]

Im using SQL server 2012 - See below for sql insert mock table

I tried it with a Case but I still have the same issue as the versionId is not unique. In both attempts i get the same record set back.

```
CASE 
 WHEN CONVERT(varchar(1), CAST(c.active AS varchar)) + CONVERT(varchar(1), CAST(c.approved AS varchar)) = ''10'' THEN 1
 WHEN CONVERT(varchar(1), CAST(c.active AS varchar)) + CONVERT(varchar(1), CAST(c.approved AS varchar)) = ''00'' AND MAX(c.lastUpdate) = c.lastUpdate THEN 2
 ELSE 0
 END   AS
```

Content showing all items, live and pending.

```
  Title             |updatedDate                | versionId         | approved  | pending   | ParentCategoryId  | ChildCategoryId
=================================================================================================================================
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:11:14.100    | A744066251C0F108  | 0         | 1         | 1                 | 1
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:11:14.100    | A744066251C0F108  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 2
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:11:14.100    | A744066251C0F108  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 3
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:10:48.777    | BCD74AAD664F2FAC  | 0         | 1         | 1                 | 1
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:10:48.777    | BCD74AAD664F2FAC  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 2
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:10:48.777    | BCD74AAD664F2FAC  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 3
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:09:09.033    | A6D650EB233DBE0F  | 0         | 1         | 1                 | 1
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:09:09.033    | A6D650EB233DBE0F  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 2
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:09:09.033    | A6D650EB233DBE0F  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 3
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:07:44.780    | GV54M6764ASD3HK9  | 1         | 0         | 1                 | 1
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:07:44.780    | GV54M6764ASD3HK9  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 2
  Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:07:44.780    | GV54M6764ASD3HK9  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 3
  Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 1                 | 1
  Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 5
  Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 12
  Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 11
  Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 1
```

**What i wish to be able to return is something that will identify which is the active set of records (i.e. relevance = 1) and which are the most recently updated and pending (i.e. relevance = 2) and which to ignore (i.e. relevance = 0). Any help greatly appreciated**

```
relevance   | Title             |updatedDate                | versionId         | approved  | pending   | ParentCategoryId  | ChildCategoryId
=============================================================================================================================================
2           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:11:14.100    | A744066251C0F108  | 0         | 1         | 1                 | 1
2           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:11:14.100    | A744066251C0F108  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 2
2           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:11:14.100    | A744066251C0F108  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 3
0           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:10:48.777    | BCD74AAD664F2FAC  | 0         | 1         | 1                 | 1
0           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:10:48.777    | BCD74AAD664F2FAC  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 2
0           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:10:48.777    | BCD74AAD664F2FAC  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 3
0           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:09:09.033    | A6D650EB233DBE0F  | 0         | 1         | 1                 | 1
0           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:09:09.033    | A6D650EB233DBE0F  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 2
0           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:09:09.033    | A6D650EB233DBE0F  | 0         | 1         | 2                 | 3
1           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:07:44.780    | GV54M6764ASD3HK9  | 1         | 0         | 1                 | 1
1           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:07:44.780    | GV54M6764ASD3HK9  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 2
1           | Maths test        |2014-12-13 12:07:44.780    | GV54M6764ASD3HK9  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 3
1           | Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 1                 | 1
1           | Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 5
1           | Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 12
1           | Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 11
1           | Science test      |2014-07-04 15:53:02.000    | ARE8327FURP24KS4  | 1         | 0         | 2                 | 1
```

Since SQLFiddler is not working i've added the SQL insert here
    CREATE TABLE #content 
     (
         id                    int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
         title                 varchar(20), 
         lastUpdate           datetime, 
         versionId             varchar(30), 
         active              tinyint,
         approved               tinyint,
         parentCategoryId      int,
         childCategoryId       int
        );

```
INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:11:14' , 'A744066251C0F108' , 0   , 0   , 1     , 1  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:11:14' , 'A744066251C0F108' , 0   , 0   , 2     , 2  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:11:14' , 'A744066251C0F108' , 0   , 0   , 2     , 3  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:10:48' , 'BCD74AAD664F2FAC' , 0   , 0   , 1     , 1  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:10:48' , 'BCD74AAD664F2FAC' , 0   , 0   , 2     , 2  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:10:48' , 'BCD74AAD664F2FAC' , 0   , 0   , 2     , 3  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:09:09' , 'A6D650EB233DBE0F' , 0   , 0   , 1     , 1  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:09:09' , 'A6D650EB233DBE0F' , 0   , 0   , 2     , 2  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:09:09' , 'A6D650EB233DBE0F' , 0   , 0   , 2     , 3  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:07:44' , 'GV54M6764ASD3HK9' , 1   , 0   , 1     , 1  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:07:44' , 'GV54M6764ASD3HK9' , 1   , 0   , 2     , 2  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Maths test'  ,'2014-12-13 12:07:44' , 'GV54M6764ASD3HK9' , 1   , 0   , 2     , 3  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Science test' ,'2014-07-04 15:53:02' , 'ARE8327FURP24KS4' , 1   , 0   , 1     , 1  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Science test' ,'2014-07-04 15:53:02' , 'ARE8327FURP24KS4' , 1   , 0   , 2     , 5  );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Science test' ,'2014-07-04 15:53:02' , 'ARE8327FURP24KS4' , 1   , 0   , 2     , 12 );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Science test' ,'2014-07-04 15:53:02' , 'ARE8327FURP24KS4' , 1   , 0   , 2     , 11 );


INSERT INTO #content
(title, lastUpdate, versionId, active, approved, parentCategoryId, childCategoryId)
VALUES ('Science test' ,'2014-07-04 15:53:02' , 'ARE8327FURP24KS4' , 1   , 0   , 2     , 1  );

select * from #content
```

Comment: What do you want to do ? - Because not all the fields against the same versionId are unique, i'm unable to select MAX(updateDate), [all the other fields] group by [all other fields]

Comment: btw, your sql has an error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'auto_increment'. It should be - id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY

Comment: re. identity column, thanks for pointing it out, it matters not as sqlFiddle is still not working.

Comment: What i want to do is be able to 'rank' the relevant content like i've illustrated in the second record set or even remove the unwanted row (i.e. those with relevance =0)

Comment: What i want to do is be able to 'rank' the relevant content like i've illustrated in the second record set by using the combination active = 1 and approved = 0 (rank 1) and  max(updatedDate) = updateDate, active and approved = 0 (rank 2) anything else = 0

Comment: @david-l, with the data provided in the SQL Fiddle and the requirement stated no row qualifies for rank 2 because there is no row where active and approved are 0 the same time. Can you revisit the input data?

Comment: opp! sorry about that I've now updated the inserts. However, not SQLFiddler still not working for MS SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case statement with a subquery like so:

```
select case when rc.active = 1 and rc.approved = 0 
        then 1
        when rc.lastUpdate = (select max(lastUpdate) from content where rc.title = title group by title, lastUpdate)
                and rc.active = 0 and rc.approved = 0
        then 2
        else 0
    end as Relevance,
    rc.*
from content rc
```

But please check the comment above on the question regarding the input data and rank 2.

Comment: Not yet sure how using the sub query will effect the performance of the overall query but your answer has given me what i needed. I changed the query slightly, in some instances having lastUpdated in the group by of the sub query returned more than one record so i've taken it out. thanks